# I need www to be linked

Tags: jquery, web, linkify

```
function urllinks(str){
    return str.replace(/\b((http|https):\/\/\S+)/g,'<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');
}
```

This code is replacing only "http" and "https" texts... but it doesn't replace texts that begins with "www"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't tried it

```
function urllinks(str){
    str = str.replace(/\b(www\.\S+)/g,'http://$1');
    return str.replace(/\b((http|https):\/\/\S+)/g,'<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');
}
```